# How to print the argv parameter after hooking the system call table function sys_execve

Tags: linux-kernel, hook, system-calls

as title,I hook system call table function sys_execve through ftrace,But when I print the argv parameter and the envp parameter, the printk function prints a bunch of invisible characters,What should I do to print the argv parameter normally

[image]

My OS is ubuntu18.04,Kernel version is 5.4.0,the compiler is gcc-7.5

My hook code looks like this

```
static asmlinkage long (*orig_sysexecve)(const struct pt_regs*);

asmlinkage int hook_sysexecve(const struct pt_regs *regs)
{
        char __user *filename = (char *)regs->di;
        char file_name[NAME_MAX] = {0};
        char __user *argv = (char *)regs->si;
        char __user *envp = (char *)regs->dx;
        char envp_list[NAME_MAX] = {0};
        char argv_list[NAME_MAX] = {0};

        long error1 = strncpy_from_user(file_name,filename,NAME_MAX);
        long error2 = strncpy_from_user(argv_list,argv,NAME_MAX);
        long error3 = strncpy_from_user(envp_list,envp,NAME_MAX);
        if(error1 > 0 && error2 > 0 && error3 > 0)
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "[TestSysExecve]: filename = %s | argv = %s | envp = %s\n",file_name,argv_list,envp_list);
        }
        orig_sysexecve(regs);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using `char __user **argv = (char**)regs->si; char **argvs; long error = strncpy_from_user(argvs,argv,NAME_MAX)`,but the direct compilation fails.

Also try to use `char **argv = (char**)regs->si;printk(KERN_INFO "%s",argv[0]);`,But this system is directly broken.

Comment: `argv` and `envp` do not point to strings, they point to pointers to strings. The "bunch of invisible characters" come from treating the bytes of the pointer values as string contents.

Comment: `argv[0]` in the `printk` doesn't work because `argv` is a user space pointer value, and so is `argv[0]`. See how `do_execveat_common()` in "fs/exec.c" calls `count()` to count the number of strings, and how the `get_user_arg_ptr()` function is used to extract a user-space pointer value from a user-space array of user-space pointer values. That extracted user-space pointer is something that you could pass to `strncpy_from_user()`.